# Rails Email Validation Based on Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two registration forms: one that can register with any email address and the other with just one specific domain. How to allow that from the *User.rb* model?

Something like this may work:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /.io/
```

But because I have two registration forms and the url for that form has an id of 2:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /.io/ if params[id] == 2
```

I do understand that `params` is not available in the model but based on what I want to achieve, how to accomplish this?

Basically form with `id = 1` can register with any email. Form with `id = 2` can only register with a `.io` email address (domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use for validation contexts. A `validates*` method can accept an `:on` option, which is the name of the "context" in which the validation will be triggered; for example:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\.io\z/, on: :restricted_email
```

This validation will only be triggered if the option `context: :restricted_email` is passed to the `save` or `save!` method. Here's how you might use it in your controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if params[:id] == 2
    @user.save!(context: :restricted_email)
  else
    @user.save!
  end
end
```

Here's a good blog post on the topic: http://blog.arkency.com/2014/04/mastering-rails-validations-contexts/

Comment: Error: `The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?`

Comment: Jordon, one last question. With your code, how easily to add more domain to the regex?

Comment: It's pretty easy to express domain names in a regular expression, e.g. `/\.(com|edu|io|co\.uk)\z/`.

Comment: An easy way to play around with regular expressions in Ruby is Rubular.com: http://rubular.com/r/QNgfdyo9sH

Answer (score 1):

You could add an attribute to the model that would indicate which form registration was coming from, like `:registered_io`, sent to your model through a hidden field in the form

```
#...
<%= f.hidden_field :registered_io, value="true" # or false %>
```

Then in your model you could just do an

```
validates :format_of_io_email_should if self.registered_io 
validates :format_of_universal_email_should if !self.registered_io

def format_of_io_email_should
 # regex ahoy or whatever
end
def format_of_universal_email_should
# same same but different
end
```

Don't forget to run your migrations to store the attribute, too!

```
$ rails migration add_column_registered_io_to_user registered_io:boolean
```

Also don't forget to allow :registered_io in the strong params in the controller.

Comment: This is the better option, in my opinion. Whatever criteria you have for restricting a user to `.io` email addresses, you are probably going to want to maintain that context after the user is created. Otherwise you have no way of knowing whether an existing user with a `.io` email address belonged to the given group or not.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method for registered_to` from the model.

Comment: `registered_to` or `registered_io`?  Head in to `$ rails console` to check it out.